# Building a good grammar with Microsoft.Speech

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, grammar

I´m having some problems building a grammar using Microsoft.Speech to build a portuguese grammar.

I built a grammar manually but it´s not good enough. I heard that I could use a Dictation Grammar in System.Speech to build my grammar but seems like it doesn´t support portuguese.

My program must be able to recognize some audio files. The sound of these audio files are very clear (and the voice is always the same). The sound consists in some letters, but I just don´t know how to build a good grammar.

Is there any way to build a letter grammar in portuguese using Microsoft.Speech?

Some sample:

```
private static readonly Dictionary<string, string> _lettersGrammar = new Dictionary<string, string>() 
    {             
        { "a",       "a" },
        { "bê",      "b" },
        { "cê",      "c" },
        { "dê",      "d" },
        { "é",       "e" },
        { "efe",     "f" },
        { "gê",      "g" },
        { "agá",     "h" },
        { "i",       "i" },
        { "jota",    "j" },
        { "cá",      "k" },
        { "ele",     "l" },
        { "eme",     "m" },
        { "ene",     "n" },
        { "ó",       "o" },
        { "pê",      "p" },
        { "quê",     "q" },
        { "erre",    "r" },
        { "esse",    "s" },
        { "tê",      "t" },
        { "u",       "u" },
        { "vê",      "v" },
        { "dáblio",  "w" },
        { "xis",     "x" },
        { "ípsilon", "y" },
        { "zê",      "x" }
    };

recognizer = new SpeechRecognitionEngine (new CultureInfo("pt-BR"));
recognizer.LoadGrammar (new Grammar (new GrammarBuilder (new Choices (_lettersGrammar.Keys.ToArray ()))) { Name = "Letters_Grammar" });

recognizer.SpeechRecognitionRejected += SpeechRecognitionRejected;
recognizer.SpeechRecognized          += SpeechRecognized;
recognizer.RecognizeCompleted        += RecognizeCompletedHandler;
```

Any suggestions?

Thank you very much guys!

Comment: It might not be the issue with the grammar. Probably your files have low quality (8khz telephony input for example).

Comment: It could be this... but the sound is so clear... and there is just a few words in the grammar... that´s strange. Thanks for your answer @NikolayShmyrev

Answer (score 2):

One thing I noticed  is that you're not setting the [`Culture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.speech.recognition.grammarbuilder.culture(v=office.14).aspx) property of the `GrammarBuilder`.  The `Culture` property of the `GrammarBuilder` must match that of the `SpeechRecognitionEngine` or else you won't get any recognitions.

The Microsoft.Speech recognition engine doesn't support dictation, so that's not an option.

The grammar you've supplied matches *one* letter.  If you want repeats, you'll need to add an intermediate [repeat GrammarBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd147100(v=office.14).aspx).

Comment: Wow thanks Erick =) awesome answer! Just to see if I understood... if it´s mandatory to have 10 letters in my audio (and only 10) I must initialize my grammar like this? new GrammarBuilder (choices, 10, 10) { Culture = new CultureInfo("pt-BR") }

Comment: Yes, that would require *exactly* 10 letters.  8 or 9 letters would not match.

Comment: That´s strange... I run a sample with 10 letters... and the result was ok... then I included this 10,10 parameter and returned 0 matches.. whaaaaaaaaaat? oO

Comment: Hard to diagnose without up to date source.